# Get List with MDS (Minimal Download Strategy) enabled

Tags: 2013, development, mds

Consider the following code:

```
string srcUrl = Request.Params["sourceUrl"]; 
SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.GetList(srcUrl);
```

---

**with MDS Feature disabled**:

```
string srcUrl = "http://localhost/Freigegebene%20Dokumente/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
```

code is executed fine

**with MDS Feature enabled**:

```
string srcUrl = "http://localhost/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Freigegebene%20Dokumente/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
```

`FileNotFoundException` occurs in the `GetList()` method

Is there another method of getting the list? Or a workaround when MDS is enabled?

Comment: You can try  string relativeurl = SPContext.Current.Web.GetServerRelativeUrlFromUrl(srcUrl); and then use relative url to get the list.

Comment: Not pretty but what about:  

if( srcUrl.Contains("/_layouts/15/start.aspx#") {
    srcUrl = srcUrl.Replace("/_layouts/15/start.aspx#", "");
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped to use another parameter called: `listId`

```
string listId = Request.Params["listId"];
Guid listIdGuid = new Guid(listId);
list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[listIdGuid];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to access list by `SourceUrl` property from a query string?

Use [SPContext.Current.List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.list(v=office.15).aspx) to gets the list that is associated with the SharePoint context:

```
SPList currentList = SPContext.Current.List;
```

Update

Use [SPWeb.GetListFromWebPartPageUrl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlistfromwebpartpageurl(v=office.15).aspx) to get the list that is associated with the first Web Part on the specified Web Parts page, for example:

```
SPList  list = SPContext.Current.Web.GetListFromWebPartPageUrl(srcUrl);
```

where `srcUrl` points to a list view url from your example.

Comment: In this particular scenario `SPContext.Current.List` is `null`

Comment: I see, please check the updated answer